# python - sqlite InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

i am using sqlite3 to store values into database, My problem is i have created lineedits through which i extract values and store it to variables and pass this variables to  insert query but i am getting above error at line values(?,?,?,?,?)......if i hard quote the values directly to variables it gets saved into database what is the mistake am i doing? please help.......here is my code

```
            self.uname = self.le1.text()
            self.passwd = self.le2.text()
            self.permssn = self.le3.text()
            self.queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER
            (USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL, PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL, PERMISSION TEXT NOT NULL)''')
            self.queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, PERMISSION) 
            VALUES(?,?,?)''',(self.uname,self.passwd,self.permssn))
            print ('inserted row')
            self.createDb.commit()
```

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The method from where you're getting the text "le1.text()", doesn't stores the value in string format. I was getting the same error, sorted out that my data type was mismatched. I converted this value to string and it worked fine.

Also don't miss to add comma in the end because the execute query takes tulip.

```
self.queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, PERMISSION) 
        VALUES(?,?,?)''',(str(self.uname),str(self.passwd),str(self.permssn),))
```

Answer (score -3):

Values should be in touple (square brackets), like this:

```
self.queryCurs.execute("INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME, PASSWORD, PERMISSION) VALUES(?,?,?)",[self.uname, self.passwd, self.permssn])
```

Since you add values at the same order as columns in your table are, you don't really need them in your query, so this will also work:

```
self.queryCurs.execute("INSERT INTO USER VALUES(?,?,?)",[self.uname, self.passwd, self.permssn])
```

Comment: not for me, I've tested his code and it worked only when I've changed it like in my answer