# insert a dictionary in a database SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

here I try to put a dictionary in an SQLite database

```
         data1 = {
               'x': x,
               'y': y,
               'width': width,
               'height':height,
               'proba': proba,
                'class': label,
                'id_label': id_label
            }
            
            sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQL_bdd.db')
            cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
            sqliteConnection.execute('''CREATE TABLE dic (
                x        INT           NOT NULL,
                y        INT           NOT NULL,
                width    INT           NOT NULL,
                height   INT           NOT NULL,
                proba    BOOLEAN       NOT NULL,
                class    VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
                id_label INT           NOT NULL
                );''')
            
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dic VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [dict['x'], dict['y'], dict['width'], dict['height'], dict['proba'], dict['class'], dict['id_label']]);
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dic")
```

the following error this occurs and I don't know how to fix it

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dic VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [dict['x'], dict['y'], dict['width'], dict['height'], dict['proba'], dict['class'], dict['id_label']]);

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Your variable name is data1 not dict.  In other words change this dict['x'], dict['y'] to data1['x'], data1['y']

Comment: thank you very much, but suddenly I have another error :-( or I can put a try except and how please 
                                                 
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dic VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [data1['x'], data1['y'], data1['width'], data1['height'], data1['proba'], data1['class'], data1['id_label']]);
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Answer (score 0):

Use **data1**['x'], data1['y'], etc. instead of **dict**['x'], dict['y'], etc. to index the data in your data1 dictionary.

Comment: thank you very much, but suddenly I have another error :-( or I can put a try except and how please cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dic VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [data1['x'], data1['y'], data1['width'], data1['height'], data1['proba'], data1['class'], data1['id_label']]); sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Comment: hmm... try researching this related question for your [error binding parameter 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981709/error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported-type/36907410) or this [sqlite3-specific edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231264/python-sqlite-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupported) of your problem

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: this is beyond the scope of your original question. but you might try changing your list `[dict1['x'], dict1['y'], ...]` to a tuple `(dict1['x'], dict1['y'], ...)`.

Comment: the hooks had to be removed cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dic VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(str(data1['x']), str(data1['y']), str(data1['width']), str(data1['height']), str(data1['proba']), str(data1['class']), str(data1['id_label']))) to view them cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM dic") ?      ;-)